# Checkbox and state in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a checkbox and a textfield in React Js. Textfield works fine but my checkbox does not change its state from the one assigned in the constructor. I am not able to find any mistake in my method "handleChange". Kindly help

My component is

```
import React from "react"
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: "",
           work1: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    } 
    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({[name]: checked}) :    this.setState({[name]: value})
    }
    render() {  
        return (
            <div className="todo-item">
                <input 
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange = {this.handleChange}  
                    checked={this.state.work1}   
                />
                <input
                    type = "text" 
                    name= "name"
                    value= {this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange }

                />     
              <p >{this.state.name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    }
export default App
```

Comment: It doesnt have a name

Comment: It worked but as i am a beginner in React can u tell why is it important to use name

Comment: Because you're using the name to set the state. `this.setState({[name]: checked})`

Comment: because you make use of if :D `this.setState({[**name**]: checked})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not give the checkbox field name property like below

```html
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  name="work1"
  onChange = {this.handleChange}  
  checked={this.state.work1}   
/>
```